# Rails - Iterate Through Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a params which I pass that looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xx==",
 "item_0"=>{"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"], "3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]},
 "item_1"=>{"0"=>["address_2"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["DEF"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]},
 "item_2"=>{"0"=>["address_3"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["GHI"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}}
```

How do I iterate over this param to get the values of each item?  I know I can grab each item individually, but when submitting dynamic form data, I won't know the exact number of items that are in the params.  How can I get around that problem?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Do you have an example of what you want your result to look like?

Comment: I've updated my question to include some of the other things that my params would contain when doing form submission.  I basically want to be able to only gather information from the items and ignore anything else, such as doing a `params[:item_0][:0]` to grab the address value.  Hope that makes more sense...

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, show us the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you're having. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to solve the problem for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: It's a much nicer pattern to put all of the "item_" params underneath a single param, eg  `hsh = {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xx==", :items => {"item_0"=>{"0"=> etc}, "item_1" => {"1" => etc}}}`.  Then you can just work with `params[:items]` as is.  This comment di

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep only keys that you want, you could use [`Hash#keep_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if) to do something like this:

```
hsh = {"utf8"=>"✓",
       "authenticity_token"=>"xx==",
       "item_0"=>{"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"], "3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]},
       "item_1"=>{"0"=>["address_2"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["DEF"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]},
       "item_2"=>{"0"=>["address_3"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["GHI"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}}

hsh.keep_if {|k, v| k=~ /item_/ }
```

and that would return:

```
{"item_0"=>{"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"], "3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]}, 
"item_1"=>{"0"=>["address_2"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["DEF"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]},
"item_2"=>{"0"=>["address_3"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["GHI"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}}
```

You can loop through a `Hash` with `each_pair`. Each pair takes to arguments e.g. `|k, v|` representing the key/value pair. From there you can do as you'd like with the hash. Since your hash is nested, I drew up this example:

```
hsh = {"item_0"=>{"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"],"3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]},
       "item_1"=>{"0"=>["address_2"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["DEF"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]},
       "item_2"=>{"0"=>["address_3"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["GHI"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}}

> hsh.each_pair {|k, v| v.each_pair {|j, w| puts w } }
address_1
model 1
ABC
Off
Status
address_2
model 1
DEF
On
Status
address_3
model 1
GHI
On
Status
```

[Here's](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair) a link to the docs for `Hash#each_pair`.

There's a number of methods to loop through hashes. For example, [`each_key`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_key) and [`each_value`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_value), which work pretty much as named.

Comment: What if the hash has more than items though?  On form submission I get other data such as `authenticity_token`, etc.  How do I ignore those and only get the items?

Comment: You can use `keep_if{|k,v| block} -> hsh` to keep only keys you want. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks - `keep_if` was what I was looking for.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags in your text. Instead, incorporate the information into the answer (or your question if that's the case). SO maintains revision history if we need to know what changed. Providing a cohesive and readable answer (or question) is the most important goal. See  "[Should 'Edit:' in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/)".

Answer (score 4):

```
hash = {"item_0"=>{"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"], "3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]}, "item_1"=>{"0"=>["address_2"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["DEF"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}, "item_2"=>{"0"=>["address_3"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["GHI"], "3"=>["On"], "4"=>["Status"]}}

hash.each do |k1, h1|
  #eg: k1 = "item_0"; h1 = {"0"=>["address_1"], "1"=>["model 1"], "2"=>["ABC"], "3"=>["Off"], "4"=>["Status"]}
  h1.each do |k2,arr|
    #eg: k2 = "0"; arr = ["address_1"]
    val = arr.first
    puts "do something with k1 = #{k1.inspect}, k2 = #{k2.inspect}, val = #{val.inspect} here"
  end
end
```

I use a similar sort of pattern with a request to update multiple objects, where I send through params with this structure:

```
params = {:resources => {123 => {:name => "Foo", :address => "bar"}, 456 => {:name => "Boo", :address => "Far"}}}
```

then in my code I can do

```
params[:resources].each do |id, attrs|
  if resource = Resource.find_by_id(id)
    resource.update_attributes(attrs)
  end
end
```

which could be written in a more long-winded way as

```
params[:resources].each do |id, attrs|
  if resource = Resource.find_by_id(id)
    attrs.each do |k,v|
      resource.send("#{k}=", v)
    end
    resource.save
  end
end
```

Comment: On form submission, I have more than just item_0, item_1, etc that show up.  I've updated my question to include examples of those.  Wondering how I ignore those values while still getting the items.